# mysql - alter table with ~15M rows and with ~200 partitions (daily) takes too long

Tags: mysql, alter-table, database-partitioning

I have a table with about 15M rows.
Each row has a timestamp.
The table has daily partitions for the last 2 months and for the 4 next months

I'm trying to run "alter table" query and it is running for like an hour and still has not completed.

The total table size is about 12GB

Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `field1` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `field3` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `field4` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field5` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field6` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field7` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field8` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field9` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field9` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `field10` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field11` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field12` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `field13` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `field14` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `field15` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `field16` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `field17` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `field18` TEXT NULL,
    `field19` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field12`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `uid` (`field3`, `field3`),
    INDEX `inst_date` (`field2`),
    INDEX `offer_id` (`field4`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
AUTO_INCREMENT=15559118
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field2))
(PARTITION p20150925 VALUES LESS THAN (1443139200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20150926 VALUES LESS THAN (1443225600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20150927 VALUES LESS THAN (1443312000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20150928 VALUES LESS THAN (1443398400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20150929 VALUES LESS THAN (1443484800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20150930 VALUES LESS THAN (1443571200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151001 VALUES LESS THAN (1443657600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151002 VALUES LESS THAN (1443744000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151003 VALUES LESS THAN (1443830400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151004 VALUES LESS THAN (1443916800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151005 VALUES LESS THAN (1444003200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151006 VALUES LESS THAN (1444089600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151007 VALUES LESS THAN (1444176000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151008 VALUES LESS THAN (1444262400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151009 VALUES LESS THAN (1444348800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151010 VALUES LESS THAN (1444435200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151011 VALUES LESS THAN (1444521600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151012 VALUES LESS THAN (1444608000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151013 VALUES LESS THAN (1444694400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151014 VALUES LESS THAN (1444780800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151015 VALUES LESS THAN (1444867200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151016 VALUES LESS THAN (1444953600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151017 VALUES LESS THAN (1445040000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151018 VALUES LESS THAN (1445126400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151019 VALUES LESS THAN (1445212800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151020 VALUES LESS THAN (1445299200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151021 VALUES LESS THAN (1445385600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151022 VALUES LESS THAN (1445472000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151023 VALUES LESS THAN (1445558400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151024 VALUES LESS THAN (1445644800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151025 VALUES LESS THAN (1445731200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151026 VALUES LESS THAN (1445817600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151027 VALUES LESS THAN (1445904000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151028 VALUES LESS THAN (1445990400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151029 VALUES LESS THAN (1446076800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151030 VALUES LESS THAN (1446163200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151031 VALUES LESS THAN (1446249600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151101 VALUES LESS THAN (1446336000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151102 VALUES LESS THAN (1446422400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151103 VALUES LESS THAN (1446508800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151104 VALUES LESS THAN (1446595200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151105 VALUES LESS THAN (1446681600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151106 VALUES LESS THAN (1446768000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151107 VALUES LESS THAN (1446854400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151108 VALUES LESS THAN (1446940800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151109 VALUES LESS THAN (1447027200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151110 VALUES LESS THAN (1447113600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151111 VALUES LESS THAN (1447200000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151112 VALUES LESS THAN (1447286400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151113 VALUES LESS THAN (1447372800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151114 VALUES LESS THAN (1447459200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151115 VALUES LESS THAN (1447545600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151116 VALUES LESS THAN (1447632000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151117 VALUES LESS THAN (1447718400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151118 VALUES LESS THAN (1447804800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151119 VALUES LESS THAN (1447891200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151120 VALUES LESS THAN (1447977600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151121 VALUES LESS THAN (1448064000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151122 VALUES LESS THAN (1448150400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151123 VALUES LESS THAN (1448236800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151124 VALUES LESS THAN (1448323200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151125 VALUES LESS THAN (1448409600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151126 VALUES LESS THAN (1448496000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151127 VALUES LESS THAN (1448582400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151128 VALUES LESS THAN (1448668800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151129 VALUES LESS THAN (1448755200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151130 VALUES LESS THAN (1448841600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151201 VALUES LESS THAN (1448928000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151202 VALUES LESS THAN (1449014400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151203 VALUES LESS THAN (1449100800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151204 VALUES LESS THAN (1449187200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151205 VALUES LESS THAN (1449273600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151206 VALUES LESS THAN (1449360000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151207 VALUES LESS THAN (1449446400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151208 VALUES LESS THAN (1449532800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151209 VALUES LESS THAN (1449619200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151210 VALUES LESS THAN (1449705600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151211 VALUES LESS THAN (1449792000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151212 VALUES LESS THAN (1449878400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151213 VALUES LESS THAN (1449964800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151214 VALUES LESS THAN (1450051200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151215 VALUES LESS THAN (1450137600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151216 VALUES LESS THAN (1450224000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151217 VALUES LESS THAN (1450310400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151218 VALUES LESS THAN (1450396800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151219 VALUES LESS THAN (1450483200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151220 VALUES LESS THAN (1450569600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151221 VALUES LESS THAN (1450656000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151222 VALUES LESS THAN (1450742400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151223 VALUES LESS THAN (1450828800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151224 VALUES LESS THAN (1450915200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151225 VALUES LESS THAN (1451001600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151226 VALUES LESS THAN (1451088000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151227 VALUES LESS THAN (1451174400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151228 VALUES LESS THAN (1451260800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151229 VALUES LESS THAN (1451347200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151230 VALUES LESS THAN (1451433600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20151231 VALUES LESS THAN (1451520000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160101 VALUES LESS THAN (1451606400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160102 VALUES LESS THAN (1451692800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160103 VALUES LESS THAN (1451779200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160104 VALUES LESS THAN (1451865600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160105 VALUES LESS THAN (1451952000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160106 VALUES LESS THAN (1452038400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160107 VALUES LESS THAN (1452124800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160108 VALUES LESS THAN (1452211200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160109 VALUES LESS THAN (1452297600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160110 VALUES LESS THAN (1452384000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160111 VALUES LESS THAN (1452470400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160112 VALUES LESS THAN (1452556800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160113 VALUES LESS THAN (1452643200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160114 VALUES LESS THAN (1452729600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160115 VALUES LESS THAN (1452816000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160116 VALUES LESS THAN (1452902400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160117 VALUES LESS THAN (1452988800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160118 VALUES LESS THAN (1453075200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160119 VALUES LESS THAN (1453161600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160120 VALUES LESS THAN (1453248000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160121 VALUES LESS THAN (1453334400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160122 VALUES LESS THAN (1453420800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160123 VALUES LESS THAN (1453507200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160124 VALUES LESS THAN (1453593600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160125 VALUES LESS THAN (1453680000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160126 VALUES LESS THAN (1453766400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160127 VALUES LESS THAN (1453852800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160128 VALUES LESS THAN (1453939200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160129 VALUES LESS THAN (1454025600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160130 VALUES LESS THAN (1454112000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160131 VALUES LESS THAN (1454198400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160201 VALUES LESS THAN (1454284800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160202 VALUES LESS THAN (1454371200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160203 VALUES LESS THAN (1454457600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160204 VALUES LESS THAN (1454544000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160205 VALUES LESS THAN (1454630400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160206 VALUES LESS THAN (1454716800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160207 VALUES LESS THAN (1454803200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160208 VALUES LESS THAN (1454889600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160209 VALUES LESS THAN (1454976000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160210 VALUES LESS THAN (1455062400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160211 VALUES LESS THAN (1455148800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160212 VALUES LESS THAN (1455235200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160213 VALUES LESS THAN (1455321600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160214 VALUES LESS THAN (1455408000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160215 VALUES LESS THAN (1455494400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160216 VALUES LESS THAN (1455580800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160217 VALUES LESS THAN (1455667200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160218 VALUES LESS THAN (1455753600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160219 VALUES LESS THAN (1455840000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160220 VALUES LESS THAN (1455926400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160221 VALUES LESS THAN (1456012800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160222 VALUES LESS THAN (1456099200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160223 VALUES LESS THAN (1456185600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160224 VALUES LESS THAN (1456272000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160225 VALUES LESS THAN (1456358400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160226 VALUES LESS THAN (1456444800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160227 VALUES LESS THAN (1456531200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160228 VALUES LESS THAN (1456617600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160229 VALUES LESS THAN (1456704000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160301 VALUES LESS THAN (1456790400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160302 VALUES LESS THAN (1456876800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160303 VALUES LESS THAN (1456963200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160304 VALUES LESS THAN (1457049600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160305 VALUES LESS THAN (1457136000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160306 VALUES LESS THAN (1457222400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160307 VALUES LESS THAN (1457308800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160308 VALUES LESS THAN (1457395200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160309 VALUES LESS THAN (1457481600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160310 VALUES LESS THAN (1457568000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160311 VALUES LESS THAN (1457654400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160312 VALUES LESS THAN (1457740800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160313 VALUES LESS THAN (1457827200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160314 VALUES LESS THAN (1457913600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160315 VALUES LESS THAN (1458000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160316 VALUES LESS THAN (1458086400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160317 VALUES LESS THAN (1458172800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160318 VALUES LESS THAN (1458259200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160319 VALUES LESS THAN (1458345600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160320 VALUES LESS THAN (1458432000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160321 VALUES LESS THAN (1458518400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160322 VALUES LESS THAN (1458604800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160323 VALUES LESS THAN (1458691200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160324 VALUES LESS THAN (1458777600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160325 VALUES LESS THAN (1458864000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160326 VALUES LESS THAN (1458950400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160327 VALUES LESS THAN (1459036800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160328 VALUES LESS THAN (1459123200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160329 VALUES LESS THAN (1459209600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160330 VALUES LESS THAN (1459296000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160331 VALUES LESS THAN (1459382400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160401 VALUES LESS THAN (1459468800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160402 VALUES LESS THAN (1459555200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160403 VALUES LESS THAN (1459641600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160404 VALUES LESS THAN (1459728000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160405 VALUES LESS THAN (1459814400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160406 VALUES LESS THAN (1459900800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160407 VALUES LESS THAN (1459987200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160408 VALUES LESS THAN (1460073600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160409 VALUES LESS THAN (1460160000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160410 VALUES LESS THAN (1460246400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160411 VALUES LESS THAN (1460332800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160412 VALUES LESS THAN (1460419200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160413 VALUES LESS THAN (1460505600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160414 VALUES LESS THAN (1460592000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160415 VALUES LESS THAN (1460678400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160416 VALUES LESS THAN (1460764800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160417 VALUES LESS THAN (1460851200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160418 VALUES LESS THAN (1460937600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160419 VALUES LESS THAN (1461024000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160420 VALUES LESS THAN (1461110400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160421 VALUES LESS THAN (1461196800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160422 VALUES LESS THAN (1461283200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160423 VALUES LESS THAN (1461369600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160424 VALUES LESS THAN (1461456000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160425 VALUES LESS THAN (1461542400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160426 VALUES LESS THAN (1461628800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160427 VALUES LESS THAN (1461715200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160428 VALUES LESS THAN (1461801600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160429 VALUES LESS THAN (1461888000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160430 VALUES LESS THAN (1461974400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160501 VALUES LESS THAN (1462060800) ENGINE = InnoDB)  */;
```

the alter table sql

```
ALTER TABLE `clicks`
    ADD COLUMN `NEW_FIELD` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `LAST_FIELD`;
```

Comment: Show your table structure and `ALTER` command. Do you add column, change datatype, add constraint?

Comment: I think i cannot do this from security reasons

Comment: So your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm adding the create table with generic fields

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461085/inserting-new-column-in-mysql-taking-too-long

Comment: Would posting hardware specs help? SSD storage, usable memory, etc.? At this scale, it may be an issue. lad's linked question looks pretty comprehensive, actually.

Comment: I think that the best way is as described in the post lad2025